# Is the intersection of any set S with another bounded set T in some metric space bounded?

Tags: general-topology, analysis

Sorry if this question is obvious but while working through Apostol's *Mathematical Analysis*, I came across this exercise

Prove each of the following statements concerning an arbitrary metric space (M, d) a subsets S, T of M.

3.39 If S is closed and T is compact, then the intersection of S and T is compact.

Here's my idea:

(1) Since T is compact, it is closed and bounded.

(2) The intersection of closed sets is closed.

(3) The intersection of any set with a bounded set is bounded.

(4) Then the intersection of S and T, let's name it A, is closed and bounded.

(5) If F is a covering of A, Heine-Borel gives us a finite subcover of A. Thus A is compact.

My question is with line (3). Though it seems obviously true, I couldn't find information on it online.

Comment: I don't see in what (5) is a consequence of what have been said above. Notice that in $(M,d)$ is a priori not true that closed and bounded set are compact. The claim follows from the fact that $T\cap S$ is closed, and from the fact that $T\cap S\subset T$ is sequentially compact.

Comment: It is true that intersection of a bounded subset with any other subset is bounded. However there is no Heine-Borel theorem for metric spaces.

Comment: Yeah, i just assumed that it is complete since the concept of completeness in metric spaces hasn't been tackled yet in the book

Comment: @Ganyuuenjoyer There is no Heine-Borel theorem for complete metric spaces either.

Comment: What restrictions should be placed on M for Heine-Borel to come home? i mistakenly thought it was completeness

Comment: @Ganyuuenjoyer A Heine-Borel like property holds in proper metric spaces. But that is essentially how proper metric spaces are defined. Complete infinite dimensional norm spaces  are a counter example to a general Heine-Borel theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Each subset of a bounded set $T$ is obviously bounded, and  the intersection of any set $S$ with a bounded set $T$ is a a subset of $T$. Thus $(3)$ is true.

Unfortunately this does not help you. It seems you believe that closed bounded subsets of a metric space $(M,d)$ are compact, but this is not true in general. Yes, there are special cases (for example $M = \mathbb R^n$ with the standard Euclidean metric $d_{eucl}$) where all closed bounded subsets are compact, but this is an untypical property.

In fact, each non-compact bounded metric space $(M,d)$ provides a counterexample: $M$ is closed and bounded, but not compact.

Given any metric space $(M,d)$ , we can define a new metric on $M$ by
$$d'(x,y) = \min (1, d(x,y)) .$$
Then $(M,d')$ is a bounded metric space such that  $(M,d)$ and  $(M,d')$ have the same open sets.

You can do this with $(\mathbb R^n,d_{eucl})$ and get $(\mathbb R^n,d'_{eucl})$ which is a non-compact bounded metric space.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. From en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heine%E2%80%93Borel_theorem the metric space of rational numbers (or indeed any incomplete metric space) fails to have the Heine–Borel property so I erroneously assumed that complete metric spaces have this property.